# Firebase Firestore - Multiple array-contains in a compound query

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

### Introduction

I am adding a chat to my app (without groups, only individuals chats (between 2 users)) where if one user deletes his full chat with other user, both users will not be able to read their previous conversation, likes happens on Telegram.

### Database model

With this use case, I don't need database denormalization at all.

This is my NoSql model:

```
usernames/ (collection) 
     jack/ (document)
         -userId: "41b932028490"
     josh/ (document)
         -userId: "212930294348"

users/ (collection)
     41b932028490/ (document)
         -avatar: {uri}
         -username: jack
         -...other data
     212930294348/ (document)
         -avatar: {uri}
         -username: "josh"
         -...other data

chats/ (collection)
      chatId/ (document) <------------ (Some kind of chat room)
           -members: ["41b932028490", "212930294348"]
           messages/ (sub-collection)
               message1Id/ (document)
                   -userId: "41b932028490" // sender
                   -type: "text" 
                   -text: "hello world!"

               message2Id/ (document)
                   -userId: "41b932028490" // sender
                   -type: "GIF"
                   -uri: "https://media.giphy.com/media/HP7mtfNa1E4CEqNbNL/giphy.gif"
```

### Problem

The problem I am having is with the logic to create the chat rooms. As you can see, I have a field "members", with the ids of both users. What I have thought to do is just making a query and trying to find the room where both users (the message's sender and the message's receiver) are members, in the chats collection. If the room exists, I will only have to add the message. If not, I will have to create the room with the new first message.

For example, if a user "Jack" is going to send a first message to the user "Josh" (the chat room doesn't exist yet), the server will firstly create a chat room (with both users as members), and the new first message as data.

But... what would happen if both users send the message at the same time? (Inconsistencie: 2 chat rooms might be created). To avoid those kinds of inconsistencies, I am running this logic atomically, in a database transaction, like this:

```
await firestore.runTransaction((transaction) => {
      // Does the chat room exists in the chats' collection?
      const chatsRef = firestore.collection("chats");
      return chatsRef
        .where("members", "array-contains", fromId) <--------- PROBLEM!
        .where("members", "array-contains", toId) <----------- PROBLEM!
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (!snapshot.empty) {
            // If yes, add the message to the chat room
            const chatRoom = snapshot.docs[0];
            const chatRoomPath = chatRoom.ref.path;
            const newMessageRef = firestore
              .doc(chatRoomPath)
              .collection("messages")
              .doc(); // Auto-generated uuid

            const newMessageData = {
              userId: fromId,
              message,
              date: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            };

            transaction.set(newMessageRef, newMessageData);
          } else {
            // TODO - Check that the receiver exists in the database (document read)
            // TODO - If exists -> create chat room with the new message
            // TODO - If not exists -> throw error
          }

          // TODO - Increment the chat counter for the receiver when adding the message
        });
    });
```

But, the docs says

> you can include at most one array-contains or array-contains-any clause in a compound query.

This is where i'm stuck, as I need to find a room with both users as members... and the only other way I can think of is to perform two queries (an OR)

```
 where("member1", "==", fromId).where("memeber2", "==", toId)

 // and

 where("member1", "==", toId).where("memeber2", "==", fromId)
```

How can I make this work with a single query? Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an array, I have used a map where the key is the user's id, and the value a true boolean.

```
 members = {
    "832384798238912789": true,
    "90392p2010219021ud": true,
 }
```

Then I query like:

```
 .where(`members.${fromId}`, "==", true)
 .where(`members${toId}`, "==", true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create an extra field in the chats document with for example a concatenation of both user ids. You can do it in the same transaction of the chat room creation or with a firebase function.
This would simplify the query since you just search for this new field:

```
where("membersconcat", "==", fromId+toId)
```

It took me a while to accept these kind of extra fields but it really avoid a lot of struggling with limitations of firestore queries